# Interior, exterior, boundary, isolated points and accumulation points in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let
$$A = \{(2, 0), (-2, 0), (0, 2)\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 < 1\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 = 1, x^1 \leq 0\}.$$
Intuitively, I know that
$$\text{int}(A) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 < 1\};$$
$$\text{ext}(A) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 > 1\} \setminus \{(2, 0), (-2, 0), (0, 2)\},$$
$$A^i = \{(2, 0), (-2, 0), (0, 2)\},$$
$$A' = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 \leq 1\},$$
but I can't formalize it. Can you please help me?

Comment: What are your definitions of these objects?

Comment: $a \in \text{int}(A)$ if and only if there exists $s > 0$ such that $B(a, s) \cap A = B(a, s)$; $b \in \text{ext}(A)$ if and only if there exists $r > 0$ such that $B(b, r) \cap A = \emptyset$; $A^i$ is the set of isolated points of $A$, and $A'$ is the derived set of $A$

Comment: So $\text{ext}(A)=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \text{int}(A)$?

Comment: It is $\text{ext}(A)\cup\partial(A) = \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\text{int}(A)$, where $\partial(A)$ is the boundary of $A$.

Comment: You are working in the set, $\mathbb R^2$, with a Euclidean topology which means that you measure distance by Euclidean metric, so you will sure have all shapes of open sets, but a typical one is an open circle $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < r, \text{ for } r \in \mathbb{R}\}$. I think from here, you can apply your definitions that use open set.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that $\text{int}(A)=\{ x\in A: \exists\delta_x>0 \quad \text{s.t}\quad B_{\delta_x}(x)\subseteq A \}$ where $B_{\delta}(x):= \{ y\in \mathbb{R}^2: \Vert x-y\Vert_2<\delta \}$, then you can show the statements as follows.

**Interior:** Then you want to show that $\text{int}(A)=B_1\big( (0,0) \big)$. Note that for all $x\notin B_1\big( (0,0) \big)$ and any $\delta>0$, $B_{\delta}(x)\cap A^c\neq \emptyset$, showing $\text{int}(A)\subseteq B_1\big( (0,0) \big)$. For $x\in B_1\big( (0,0) \big)$, consider $\delta_x= \frac{1-\Vert x\Vert_2}{2}$ and use triangle inequality.

**Isolated points:** To show $A^i=\{ (2, 0), (-2, 0), (0, 2) \}$, consider balls around these points of radius $1$ and whether they intersect $A$ without the center point.

**Limit points:** Show that for all $\delta>0$, you have $\Big(B_{\delta}(x)\setminus \{x\}\Big)\cap A\neq \emptyset$ if and only if $\Vert x\Vert_2\leq 1$. If $\delta< \Vert x\Vert_2$, you can check this for  $y=(1-\delta)x $.

**Boundary:** To show that $\partial A =\{ x: \Vert x\Vert_2= 1 \}\cup \{ (2, 0), (-2, 0), (0, 2) \}$, note first that $A^i\subseteq \partial A$ always. Limit\accumulation points  of both $A$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$ are the part of the boundary that are not isolated points. So you just need to show for all $\delta>0$, that $\Vert x\Vert_2=1$ if and only if $B_\delta(x)\cap \big( \mathbb{R}^2\setminus A\big)\neq \emptyset$ and $x\notin A^i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood it perfectly, except for the last part. What do you mean I can check that for $y = (1 - \delta)x$?

Comment: Do you mean I can see that $||y||_2 \leq 1$?

Comment: You want to find a point in the intersection of the sets. I am suggesting a point along the same line to the origin just multiplied by a factor of $1-\delta$.

Comment: Clearly $(0,2)$ is not an isolated point of $A$ because any neighborhood of $(0,2)$ contains some point of $A$. I think ext$(A) = \mathbb R^2 - (\{(2, 0), (-2, 0)\} \cup \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 \leq 1\})$; Isolate points of A are $\{(2,0), (-2,0)\}$; Boundary of $A$ is $\{ (2,0), (-2,0)\} \cup \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: |x| = 1 \}$; Interior of $A$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 < 1\}$; accumulation points of $A$ are $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 \leq 1\}$.

Comment: @user398843 I don't see why $(0,2)$ is not an isolated point. There are only 3 points of norm 2. The rest are of norm less or equal than 1. It must be then, that any point of norm  $2$ must be isolated.

Comment: @Keen-ameteur You are right. I misunderstood. I thought that the $x$ in $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 \leq 1\}$ is the $x$ coordinate of $(x,y)$. Correcting my previous comment: ext$(A)= \mathbb R^2 - A$; isolate points of $A$ are $\{ (2,0), (-2, 0), (0, 2)\}$; boundary of $A$ is $\{ (2,0), (-2, 0), (0, 2)\} \cup\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2: x^2 +y^2 = 1 \}$; interior of $A$ is $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 < 1\}$; accumulation points of $A$ are $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 \colon ||x||_2 \leq 1\}$